# replace of varible length using gsub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have dataframe with 2 string

```
1) PWH+PTR

2) PWH++PTR
```

I want to write gsub function which replace any number of '+' exiting and gives you

```
1)PWH+PTR

2)PWH+PTR
```

I tried

```
l<-data.frame(gsub("\\+\\+","+",l[,1]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[+]+` or `\\++` to match one or more `+`

```
l <- data.frame(gsub("[+]+","+", l[,1]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with the regex quantifiers `+.

```
st <- c("PWH+PTR", "PWH++PTR")
 gsub("\\++", "\\+", st)
[1] "PWH+PTR" "PWH+PTR"
```